# Which service is executing ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

A basic question. What is executing my files in ebextensions?
We use Cloudformations and elastic beanstalk to setup a windows server. In a step of ebextensions I'm executing `restart-service ec2config`. After that the ec2config service is going in stoppending mode and it's stuck for ever.

So my question: is ec2config executing ebextensions and is it stuck/broken because I tried to restart it inside my ebextensions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is only annecdotal but yes, for Windows it does appear that any bootstrapping like user-data and ebextensions is performed by ec2config.